# Как создать пользовательский виджет в виде формы?

Tags: c++, qt, виджет

**Внимание вопрос изменен(добавлен кусок кода)**

Всем привет!

Как создать пользовательский виджет в виде формы, и потом можно было его двигать по форме.
Т.е. есть форма, и внутри него есть виджет который двигается внутри формы. И там у него например есть `LineEdit, PushButton`.

Можно через `drawline`, но так не катит, мне надо чтобы виджет двигался при удержании левой кнопки мыши

Пример формы:

[image: Пример формы]

Если невозможно, то как эту область сделать перемещаемой, через `mouse pressed`?

```
 #include <QtGui>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene(QRectF(-100, -100, 300, 300));
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    QTextEdit* text = new QTextEdit();
    text->setFixedSize(100,30);
    text->setGeometry(-40,-70,100,30);
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* widgetItem = scene.addWidget(text);
    widgetItem->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);//Так не передвигается по форме

    QPushButton cmd("Button");
    widgetItem = scene.addWidget(&cmd);
    widgetItem->setFlag(QGraphicsProxyWidget::ItemIsMovable);

    QGraphicsRectItem* rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, &scene);
    rect->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::gray));
    rect->setRect(QRectF(-20, -20, 120, 70));
    rect->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[Вот такую хочется сделать](http://i51.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0405/7e/7706933df106f4b5050b33e2a521b17e.jpg)

Получается придется добавить событие mouse pressed? Или как по примеру **alexeinaumov**, добавить класс MyWidget?

**Новый вопрос**. Походу того что кнопка нажимается или редактируется, не получается передвинуть. Тогда как можно сделать, так чтобы, внутри какой-то области(Область у нас будет задаваться через QGraphicsItem) была кнопка(QGraphicsProxyWidget) и она(с помощью QGraphicsItem) передвигалась, т.е. кнопка внутри области и с помощью области движется?

Comment: Посмотрел, получается QGraphicsWidget не использую, только наследую от него?

Comment: Можете наследоваться если удобно, можете использовать QGraphicsProxyWidget)
Из документации:
`Note: QWidget-based widgets can be directly embedded into a QGraphicsScene using QGraphicsProxyWidget.`

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Я так понимаю, что вы хотите перемещать группу объектов: кнопку и некоторую область. В этом случае используйте QGraphicsGroupItem. Добавьте в него Вашу кнопку и область.

Comment: кнопка то не Item...

Comment: Ммм.. я имел в виду кнопка как QGraphicsProxyWidget. Есть еще метод: Вы можете сделать Ваш proxy для кнопки дочерним для области например так (код не проверял):

    `QGraphicsRectItem* rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, &scene);
    rect->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::gray));
    rect->setRect(QRectF(-20, -20, 120, 70));
    rect->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

    QPushButton cmd("Button");
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *btnProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(rect, &scene); // btnProxy теперь дочерний для rect
    btnProxy->setWidget(&cmd);
    btnProxy->setFlag(QGraphicsProxyWidget::ItemIsMovable);`

Comment: так не работает, ладно, спасибо!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**.h-файл** виджета **который** перетаскиваем

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QtGui>
#include "ui_MyWidget.h"

class MyWidget : public QWidget, public Ui::MyWidgetClass
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
 ~MyWidget();

  QPoint mousePressPoint() const {return _mousePressPoint;}

protected:
  void mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent* mouseEvent);
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* mouseEvent);
  void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* mouseEvent);

signals:
  void move(const QPoint& point); // текущие координаты мыши при перетаскивании виджета

private:
  QPoint _mousePressPoint; // координаты при нажатии кнопки мыши на виджете
  bool _isBeingDragged; // выполняется ли перетаскивание виджета?
};

#endif // MYWIDGET_H
```

**.cpp-файл** виджета **который** перетаскиваем

```
#include "MyWidget.h"

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
}

void MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent* mouseEvent)
{
  if (_isBeingDragged)
    emit move(mouseEvent->pos());
}

void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* mouseEvent)
{
  _isBeingDragged = true; // начинаем перетаскивание виджета
  _mousePressPoint = mouseEvent->pos(); // сохраняем координаты нажатия кнопки мыши
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* mouseEvent)
{
  _isBeingDragged = false; // заканчиваем перетаскивание виджета
}
```

**.h-файл** виджета **на котором** перетаскиваем

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>
#include "ui_Dialog.h"

#include "MyWidget.h"

class Dialog : public QDialog, public Ui::DialogClass
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Dialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
 ~Dialog();

private slots:
  void onMove(const QPoint& point);

private:
  MyWidget* _myWidget;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**.cpp-файл** виджета **на котором** перетаскиваем

```
#include "Dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
  setupUi(this);

  _myWidget = new MyWidget(this);

  bool result = true;

  result &= connect(_myWidget, SIGNAL(move(const QPoint&)), this, SLOT(onMove(const QPoint&)));

  if (!result)
    qDebug() << "Error connecting signals and slots in " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
}

void Dialog::onMove(const QPoint& point)
{
  QRect before = _myWidget->geometry(); // расположение виджета до перетаскиваниz
  QRect after; // расположение виджета после перетаскивания

  int deltaX = point.x()-_myWidget->mousePressPoint().x(); // перемещение мыши по оси X
  int deltaY = point.y()-_myWidget->mousePressPoint().y(); // перемещение мыши по оси Y

  after.setX(before.x()+deltaX);
  after.setY(before.y()+deltaY);
  after.setWidth(before.width());
  after.setHeight(before.height());

  _myWidget->setGeometry(after); // изменение положения виджета
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Dialog.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Dialog dialog;
    dialog.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Исходники** [тут](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/103588168/HC_1.tar.gz)

Comment: Спасибо!!)
Получается что можно еще добавить виджеты которые перетаскиваем(например mywidget2.cpp)? 
Т.е. например при нажатии на кнопку push button, на виджет, на котором перетаскиваем, добавляется еще один виджет.

Comment: Добавление при нажатии сделал, сначала создаю два объекта, потом вторую ставлю setvisible(false), потом при нажатии на кнопку ставлю setvisible(true). Так правильно?)

Comment: Добавление второго виджета при нажатии на кнопку сделал, сначала создаю два объекта, потом вторую ставлю setvisible(false), потом при нажатии на кнопку ставлю setvisible(true).

Comment: В "Qt Examples and Demos" есть подробный пример создания пользовательских компонетов с возможностью перетаскивания по сцене. Называется он "Ported Canvas" и находится во вкладке "Graphics View". Как раз то, что Вы ищете.

Comment: Походу того что кнопка нажимается или редактируется не получается, как можно сделать так чтобы, внутри какой-то области(Область у нас будет задаваться через QGraphicsItem) была кнопка(QGraphicsProxyWidget) и она(через QGraphicsItem) передвигалась, т.е. кнопка с областью?

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток! 
Используйте `QGraphicsWidget` в связке с `QGraphicsScene` и `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: Наверху добавил код программы